# How do I install the Intel HD 3000 video driver?

Tags: 10.04, intel-graphics

how do I install a new video driver?

I need to install the Intel HD 3000 video driver in my PC which is running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 5):

Sandy Bridge Graphics such as the HD3000 will need an upgrade of the Mesa support beyond what is available for Lucid.

One of the [best PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver?field.series_filter=lucid) with a mesa version that has backports for Sandy Bridge support is from [Stefan Glasenhardt](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.glasen-hardt.de/&ei=i_hTTrSYCcmz8QOZhdHxBQ&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDUQ7gEwBDgK&prev=/search?q=sandy%2bbridge%2bStefan%2bGlasenhardt&start=10&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=1Uc&sa=N&channel=fs&gl=uk&biw=1308&bih=682&prmd=ivnso).

I would NOT install the install the x-org edgers PPA which is often quoted.  x-org edgers - as the developers themselves say - is very unstable and can cause major graphics issues since updates are frequent and often sparingly tested.

Since you are using a modern laptop, you will also require the more up-to date Kernel - 2.6.38 which is available from Synaptic Manager.

### How to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

**Note**

Working with the OP - this solution only works for 32bit Ubuntu.  64bit Ubuntu with this solution will leave you with a frozen/messed up graphics and as such should be avoided.

Comment: I have followed your instructions, copying and pasting the list of commands suggested by you. Unfortunately everything went wrong. After booting my machine has frozen showing a very messed up screen. I have tried then to install the Ubuntu 11.04 with no success either. After downloading the ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso and burning the CD, when I booted from the CD all I got was the message: 'error: "prefix" is not set'. Please help me out of this.

Comment: thank you for your valuable help. After much unsuccessful strugle I've decided to install the 32 bit Natty version and everything worked all right. At the same time I am adding another question about the 64bit live Natty CD. Whenever I get a solution I will be back and install the 64 bit version.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Not only did this fix the graphics issues on my Samsung 900X3A, but it also took care of the [touchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal/+bug/880048)!

Comment: @fossfreedom nomodeset or modeset=0 disables the opensource graphics drivers, possibly leaving you with a 1024*768 resolution. `acpi=off` is also a bad idea as power consumption will raise and certain Power Management functiions may fail to work.

Comment: @Lekensteyn - agreed - I should have updated the answer to make clear that it is a 32bit solution only.  I've deleted my comments to tidy up

Answer (score 2):

Your best solution is probably to upgrade to 10.10 and then 11.04. That has the newer drivers available already.

Alternatively there are drivers for 10.04 available, with some risk of instability:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

As documented on Ubuntu's [own forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1728526).

Answer (score 0):

10.04 is way too old to get them working, you have to upgrade to 11.04.

But even with that, the Intel 3000 drivers on a Macbook Air (4,1/4,2) will not work properly because of bugs in the linux kernel. See http://keithp.com/blogs/MacBook-Air-2 for an explanation of this. The result is that you'll need Linux Kernel version 3.2 to get them fully working.

Answer (score 0):

after you did what 'fossfreedom' posted just change the following line in '/etc/default/grub'

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash"
```

to

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash i965.modeset=1"
```

*also you might see [>>this Post<<](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75164/vga-not-detected-on-a-lenovo-t420)*

Answer (score 0):

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash i965.modeset=0` is workable in sandy bridge. Also be careful while updating the system. Only use below command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

Install lucid-1.04 and use above code.

Thanks guys, after a long time, good post. Many thanks to Glasen.