# How can I fix my xvinfo?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, drivers, video, display

How can i fix my X server/driver?

```
$ xvinfo
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
 no adaptors present
```

Additional info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux desktop 2.6.32-33-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 7 21:13:52 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0100 (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 1503 (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1c4a (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Device 8892 (rev 10)
04:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation Device 0194 (rev 04)
```

**Follow up:**

- It seems in 64-bit its a mess doing existing approach.
- Therefore, after upgrading to 12.04 64-bit this problems in same hardware is resolved 
  (of-course, i have now other drivers problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sandy bridge intel graphics that are not currently supported in lucid.

My linked answer below should in theory work - although the OP had issues.

Therefore I recommend that if you want to try this, do a hard-drive image backup first with clonezilla.

Alternatively - upgrade to at least Maverick - or preferably Natty which does have native Sandy Bridge support.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I install the Intel HD 3000 video driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58376/how-do-i-install-the-intel-hd-3000-video-driver-on-ubuntu-10-04/58402#58402)