# Can I upgrade to Linux 3 Kernel on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade, kernel

I need to use Linux 3, becasue with Linux 2.6.x has display problems  with my SandyBridge integrated graphic. On the other hand, I need to downgrade to Ubuntu 10.04/10 because [Betavine](http://www.betavine.net/bvportal/resources/datacards/os/ubuntu) packages for running my mobile broadband modem work only with Ubuntu 10.04 (and 10.10). Hence I need to make a compromise. I appreciate your hints.

Comment: Sandy bridge works OK on the natty kernel - if you start from 10.04 - you can use this answer here to upgrade graphics and the kernel to work with your sandybridge laptop.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/58376/how-do-i-install-the-intel-hd-3000-video-driver-on-ubuntu-10-04/58402#58402

Comment: FYI, the difference from 2.6.x to 3.0.0 is nothing. It was just a version bump from Linus =P

Comment: I have 3.2.4 installed in Natty I just went to the mainline and downloaded the .DEBs

Answer (score 1):

Or, as a last-ditch effort you could compile a new kernel from kernel.org and use that.

To get an ubuntu-styled kernel:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
cd linux-image-$(uname -r)
make menuconfig #Then hit exit and save the configuration
cd ..
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2.6.tar.bz2
tar -xjf linux-3.2.6.tar.bz2
cd linux-3.2.6
make menuconfig
cp ../linux-image-$(uname -r)/.config .
rm -R ../linux-image-$(uname -r)*
make
make install
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe. There is an Ubuntu kernel PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa

You can try download the Linux kernel 3 for Oneiric, maybe it will work.
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: you can't use a oneiric kernel for a Ubuntu versions that's not Oneiric!