# stuck with 640x480 resolution using bumblebee on 10.04

Tags: xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I just installed bumblebee on a Dell XPS L502X. It basically works: `optirun glxspheres` does exactly what it should.

However, X is running with a resolution of 640x480. I can try to change settings with `optirun nvidia-settings -c :8` (as suggested on the bumblebee wiki), but in the relevant section it only lists resolutions up to 640x480.

In the `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.*` files, there are no `Monitor` or `Screen` sections. Adding them doesn't change anything.

How can I change the resolution?

Comment: Where do you need larger resolutions for? The resolution set by the Bumblebee X server does not affect the maximum size of regular program windows.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean... i'd like to use my gnome desktop in something bigger than a widescreen-distorted 640x480.

Comment: I guess I'm realizing what the problem is here. The NVIDIA drivers work fine, it's just that the integrated intel chip doesn't. X:0 is for the intel chip and X:8 for the nvidia one. Xorg.0.log gives me a modeline for 1366x768 but if I make a custom /etc/X11/xorg.conf with that modeline the X server won't start.

Comment: Remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and be sure **not** to install the nvidia drivers from nvidia.com on an Optimus laptop. Could you [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com) `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and put the link to it in your question?

Comment: @Lekensteyn I'm indebted to you. I've been pulling my hair out for the past two hours and it turns out the reason my screen res was broken was due to my installing the nvidia.com drivers first. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In fact the problem is not with NVIDIA or bumblebee, but the fact that Intel HD 3000 is not supported under 10.04.

There is, however, a solution using backports here: [How do I install the Intel HD 3000 video driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58376/how-do-i-install-the-intel-hd-3000-video-driver)

This worked fine for me, and didn't break the bumblebee/NVIDIA setup.