# Are Intel HD 4000 graphics supported on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, intel-graphics

I have an intel Core i7-3700 system with Intel HD 4000 integrated graphics with a dual monitor setup (1 connected via VGA, the other via DVI) on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit. I'm trying to get my monitors correctly detected. Right now, in only 1 unknown monitor is detected with a max resolution of 1280x1024, which is lower than my main monitor connected to DVI. Also, the desktop is mirrored rather than extended.

I've previously managed to get a Core i5-2400 system with Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics with the same dual monitor setup and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit to work using the glasen ppa drivers, but this time, after installing them following the instructions [How do I install the Intel HD 3000 video driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58376/how-do-i-install-the-intel-hd-3000-video-driver) but it doesn't seem to work.

Does the Intel HD 4000 require a different driver from the 3000? If so, where can I get it?

Comment: Given the state of Intel's graphics driver support for Linux, I am surprised it works at all in 10.04. Ivy Bridge has only been released 3 moths back, and full Linux graphics support is probably still a couple of years away, but 10.04 with its kernel from late 2009 will never see any of that. What you probably need is a newer driver, the one available in 12.04, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working back installing the backported oneiric kernel.

Comment: Can you tell me how to install the drivers for hd 4000 on 12.04 , i tried intellinuxgraphics.org and the autoconf isnt working :( Posted by  @deepak

Answer (score 1):

You need kernel 3.4.

Actually I have kernel 3.3 in 10.04 which works without problem, although I must try 3.4.

For further reference : [Intel 12.07 graphics package](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2012.07.html)