# Why doesn't my monitor work?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I had my HD monitor working fine, I plugged into a vga somewhere else and when I came back all I got on the HD screen was blackness.

Are there any settings that could have been changed automatically by my pluggin in to a VGA monitor?

If there are any such settings where are how do I switch them back?

(I have confirmed the problem by trying 2 different HD screens with similar results and I have tried every possible combination of display settings.)

WTF right?

Here is my `lspci -v`

```
edit:: lenovo t430 with integrated graphics   

    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: f0000000-f10fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at f3920000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f3935000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f3900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at f393b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at 6080 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f393a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f3930000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: f3100000-f38fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f1800000-00000000f1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f3000000-f30fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=0b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: f2800000-f2ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f2000000-00000000f27fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f3939000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    I/O ports at 60a8 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 60b4 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 60a0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 60b0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 6060 [size=32]
    Memory at f3938000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at f3934000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [NVS 5400M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo GF108M [NVS 5400M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f1000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f3100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 3e)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at f3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

and also `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:21f4]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [17aa:21f3]
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [NVS 5400M] [10de:0def] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo GF108M [NVS 5400M] [17aa:21f4]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f1000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

02:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller [1180:e823] (rev 07) (prog-if 01)
```

Comment: What sort of computer are you using? And do you know what video card or onboard graphics adapter you're using?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `xrandr --verbose` when you plug it to VGA and still working then again when it become black. Upload outputs to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Is it a laptop you're on? If so, sometimes there is a keyboard shortcut to switch between display ports. On my laptop it's FN(Located bottom left of keyboard) + F10.

Whichever key it is will most likely have an icon on it of a monitor and laptop side by side with a line in between.

Turns out it's FN+F7 according to the instructions of your laptop.

http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/t430_ug_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately this just makes my screen jump around for a second switching me from extended to mirrored display.  Displaying a blue flash on the hd screen followed by the usual blackness.

Comment: I managed to find this, which is someone with the same issue as you and the same graphics processor.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/167388/are-intel-hd-4000-graphics-supported-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts

May have to search for a Ubuntu Graphics driver for Intel HD 4000.

Comment: I really appreciate you pulling this up, but, do yo really think  it is a driver kernel issue if I had it working previously on this system with this install?